# button doesn't work in different frame actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, button, uinavigationcontroller

My flash file (Attached Below), has buttons that doesn't work. There **are no compiling error**, but my *NextFrame button, PrevFrame button* and *HomeButton* are only working if I click on the first button (There are four buttons).

If i choose the other buttons, my prevFr, NextFr, and Home button are not working. Here I attach the link to my sample file.

**Thank you** for everyone trying to help.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxvhVI-ULexWa0dSeEc5bVFFX1k/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have been rewritten my code and applied in one frame Please check this file...I hope this one will be helpful with clear solutions....And inside this function func i have written if instead of that use else if...

Thank you..

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6f5z55WOf3pdXVkd1hfU21Uc3c

Comment: I'm confused. You've fixed Asker's code (it works fine now)? Or you are same person as Asker and this code is a new edit but still same problem to fix?